# Issue uploading PostAction plugin in Datafusion

Tags: plugins, google-cloud-data-fusion

We are trying to implement a custom post action plugin for Datafusion. The plugin build is successful. When i try to upload the Jar and Json file. It fails with below error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 502 (Bad Gateway)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

How to debug this issue as at build time we do not see any issues.

Comment: Is this issue consistently happening or only intermittently?

Comment: Its happening consistently, my jar file size is 16mb , not sure if it is cause of the issue, after multiple retries randomly one time it got uploaded without error. But still issue persists when I try to reload it with some changes again.

Comment: This seems like a known issue that is encountered in certain cases in Chrome.
Until it is resolved, can you use Firefox or another browser besides Chrome to upload plugins?

Comment: I have tried firefox , still facing the same issue

Comment: I personally haven't been able to reproduce it. Can you try Safari as well?

Comment: You could try running your job using CDAP [1] locally to see if you are able to find some error message about your issue (Cloud Data Fusion is built on the open source project CDAP, and ensures data pipeline portability for users [2]). This way we can try to troubleshoot and also try to find a solution. Please, let us know if something changes. [1] https://cdap.io/get-started/ [2] https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/